# How to do distinct in inner join?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my code.

```
select t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ;
```

Here are the results:

```
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,1
50,2
50,2
50,2
...
49,2
49,2
49,2
49,3
49,3
49,3
49,3
49,3
49,3
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,4
49,5
49,5
49,5
49,5
49,5
49,5
```

If you see the results, duplicate values ​​come out over and over again.

I want result as like

```
50,1
49,2
49,3
49,4
49,5
```

I want to **distinct these duplicate result** values ​​in an `inner join`, but I'm curious how it is possible.

There is another problem with using subqueries.

```
select rownum, t5.SUBJECTNAME || 'project', T3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ
where (subjectseq, teamname) in (
select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ)
;
```

The value after the where statement in the subquery can only be received as `in`, so it is the same as the result without distict.

I was wondering if there is any solution to solve this.

regard best

**append**
here is all data

```
teamseq, t1.classseq, teamname, t2.classseq, studentseq, t2.opencourseseq, t.opencourseseq, coursestate, opensubjectregister, studentregister, coursestart, courseend, courseseq, classroomseq, opensubjectseq, subjectstart, subjectend, t3.availablesubjectseq, t3.opencourseseq, t4.availablesubjectseq, teahcerseq, t4.subjectseq, t5.subjectseq, subjectname, period, bookseq
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,1,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00,26,1,26,3,6,6,Java OpenJDK Programming,29,1
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,2,2021-02-16 00:00:00,2021-03-10 00:00:00,18,1,18,2,10,10,오라클을 사용한 RDBMS의 SQL과 PL/SQL,17,2
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,3,2021-03-11 00:00:00,2021-04-04 00:00:00,53,1,53,6,49,49,Front-end 클라이언트 화면설계 및 구현,16,18
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,4,2021-04-05 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,7,1,7,1,50,50,Back-end 서버프로그래밍 설계 및 구현,28,10
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
2,2,1,2,13,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
3,3,1,3,17,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
4,4,1,4,33,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
5,5,1,5,36,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
6,6,1,6,39,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
7,7,2,7,54,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
8,8,2,8,63,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
9,9,2,9,69,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
10,10,2,10,75,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
11,11,2,11,81,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
12,12,2,12,83,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
13,13,3,13,88,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
14,14,3,14,94,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
15,15,3,15,95,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
16,16,3,16,103,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
17,17,3,17,111,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
18,18,3,18,117,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
19,19,4,19,123,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
20,20,4,20,138,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
21,21,4,21,141,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
22,22,4,22,144,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
23,23,4,23,160,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
24,24,4,24,162,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
25,25,5,25,168,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
26,26,5,26,171,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
27,27,5,27,176,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
28,28,5,28,181,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
29,29,5,29,189,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
30,30,5,30,192,1,1,강의중,등록,30,2021-01-05 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,1,1,5,2021-05-13 00:00:00,2021-06-22 00:00:00,32,1,32,4,36,36,클라우드 시스템 개요 및 AWS 서비스 요소,30,7
```

Comment: `.. in (select distinct  ..)` makes no sense as `in` predicate is true when one or more matching rows were found by select. It will produce exactly one (when true) or zero (when false) rows in the output.

Comment: @Serg yes so I tried PL/SQL and `where =` but it doesn't work..

Comment: Why not just  `SELECT  DISTINCT rownum, t5.SUBJECTNAME || 'project', T3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ ..` ?

Comment: Do you know which table have the duplicate records? Just select the distinct records from that table and then join that table.  Please post some sample data also if possible.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I post data and that is what I want to know how to join that table with select the distinct records?

Comment: @Serg Because my ultimate goal is to use the insert statement after comparing with the where condition using distincted values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross apply on the table that causes duplication - example below

```
select t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME from tblteam t1
     inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
     inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
     inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
     inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 SUBJECTSEQ FROM TBLSUBJECT on SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that code is not working My tool is Oracle 11.g

Answer (score 0):

Serg's suggestion (in the comments) would give you the right result I think, but if you need to get at the root of the problem, most likely only one of the joins is causing the duplicate records. If so, a solution would be to use a subquery in that join. An example would be:

```
select t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
         inner join (select distinct CLASSSEQ, OPENCOURSESEQ from TBLCLASS t2) t2d
                    on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2d.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2d.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ;
```

But, which of the joins you would use a subquery for depends on where the duplication occurs. You could test it by attempting successive pair-wise joins:

```
select t1.TEAMNAME, t2.CLASSSEQ
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
```

Then

```
select t2.CLASSEQ, T.OPENCOURSESEQ
from TBLCLASS t2
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
```

Etc. checking each successive join to find the cause of the duplication, then applying distinct in a subquery to the one that causes the problem.

When you find one of these joins causes the duplication, you can apply distinct to this one join. Note that - if we understand correctly - the result is is not different from using distinct for the whole result at the end. It might be more efficient to cut out the duplicates early in the execution, that's all.